# Extra space inserted on new pages when creating PDFs with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp 5.0.5 to create dynamic PDFs (asp.net c#), and I'm having problems with an extra space being inserted when creating a new page. The first page looks fine but on any additional pages the extra space appears at the top.

I've made a mini example that inserts a new page with a logo and a title for each article in a list. If I only insert the logo or only the title it works fine, but if I try to insert both there's an extra space coming from somewhere. Anyone got any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
public static void CreatePDF(List<Item> Articles)
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 35, 35, 35, 35);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);

    document.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < Articles.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            document.NewPage();
        }

        Image logo = Image.GetInstance(@"C:\logo.gif");
        document.Add(logo);

        Paragraph title = new Paragraph("test title", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 20, Font.NORMAL, CMYKColor.BLACK));
        document.Add(title);
    }

    document.Close();

    SendPDFResponse(memoryStream, "myfile.pdf");
}
```

Thanks,

Annelie

Comment: It must be hard using this library... I've had a similar need in the past - started considering iTextSharp, ended up using a commercial, HTML to PDF tool (because it's so much faster and easier, and many have very good results).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no extra space on the pages that follow page 1. The problem is that there's less space on page 1.
No, this is not a joke. The problem is caused by the "leading" (that is: the space between two lines). The initial value for the leading is 0. When you add content to a document, this value changes to a value different from 0.

What is the leading you're using throughout the document? You should set this as the initial leading with the method setInitialLeading() in PdfWriter.

Comment: I'm not setting it so it's using the default value of 150% of the font size (which in the case above is 20 so leading would be 30). This might not always be the case but I'll set the initial leading to 30 and hope it looks fine! :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug.  I suspect some relatively new aspect of layout isn't being reset properly between pages.

Would you mind cross-posting this to the [itext-questions mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions)?